# Ionic 2 - Passing ID from json to child (details) page

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a provider service that calls get requests from my API. I then have a listing page whereby you can scroll though many recipes. What I am struggling with is taking the ID of each recipe and passing it to the details page as this needs to be included within.

My service request is for the listing is

```
loadCategory1() {
  var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=////&_app_key=////";

  if (this.Category1) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.Category1);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(url + "&allowedAllergy[]=396^Dairy-Free&allowedAllergy[]=393^Gluten-Free&maxResult=50&start=10")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.Category1 = data.matches;
        resolve(this.Category1);
      });
  });
}
```

and I currently have a separate one for my details as well

```
loadDetails() {
  if (this.details) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.details);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364?_app_id=//////&_app_key=//////')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.details = data;
        resolve(this.details);
      });
  });
}
```

As you can see in the  details request i have **French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364** This needs to be dynamic by taking the ID from each recipe. Example is below.

[image]

Within each .ts file I have the following

```
  loadRecipes(){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadCategory1()
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
   }
```

This allows me to call the request.

I'm at the point now where I have no clue what to do so some help would be great.

Comment: u must be having global  variable.ts file in your project structure!

Comment: the problem is you are subscribing two times in your apiAuthentication.ts file and also in your each .ts file try to subscribe only in each .ts file

Answer (score 0):

Your DetailsService can be something like this:

```
loadDetails(detailsId: string) {    
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/'+detailsId+'?_app_id=//////&_app_key=//////')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.details = data;
        resolve(this.details);
      });
  });
}
```

Navigate to DetailsPage with arguments:

```
this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage,{
            recipe: recipe
          });
```

And you can call DetailsService inside DetailsPage by using code like this:

```
loadDetails(){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails(this.recipe.id)
    .then(data => {
      this.details = data;
    });
   }
```